# Problem sorting ConcurrentHashMap by values using java.util.Collections.sort() in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have this code which prints me a list of words sorted by keys (alphabetically) from counts, my ConcurrentHashMap which stores words as keys and their frequencies as values.

```
// Method to create a stopword list with the most frequent words from the lemmas key in the json file
   private static List<String> StopWordsFile(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas) {

// counts stores each word and its frequency
       ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

// corpus is an array list for all the individual words
           ArrayList<String> corpus = new ArrayList<String>();

           for (Entry<String, String> entry : lemmas.entrySet()) {
               
               String line = entry.getValue().toLowerCase();               
               line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");
               line = line.replaceAll("\\d+"," ");
               line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
               line = line.trim();
               String[] value = line.split(" ");

               List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value));
               corpus.addAll(words);

    }

           // count all the words in the corpus and store the words with each frequency i 
           //counts
           for (String word : corpus) {

               if (counts.keySet().contains(word)) {
                   counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);

               } else {counts.put(word, 1);}
}
// Create a list to store all the words with their frequency and sort it by values.
           List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());         
           
           List<String> stopwordslist = new ArrayList<>(counts.keySet()); # this works but counts.values() gives an error
           Collections.sort(stopwordslist);
           System.out.println("List after sorting: " +stopwordslist);
```

So the output is:

```
List after sorting: [a, abruptly, absent, abstractmap, accept,...]
```

How can I sort them by values as well? when I use
List stopwordslist = new ArrayList<>(counts.values());

I get an error,

```
- Cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>
```

I guess that is because ArrayList can store < String >  but not <String,Integer> and it gets confused.

I have also tried to do it with a custom Comparator like so:

```
           Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> valueComparator = new Comparator<Entry<String,Integer>>() {
               @Override
               public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
                   String v1 = e1.getValue();
                   String v2 = e2.getValue();
                   return v1.compareTo(v2);
               }
           };  
           
           
           List<Entry<String, Integer>> stopwordslist = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>();
           // sorting HashMap by values using comparator 
           Collections.sort(counts, valueComparator)
```

which gives me another error,

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>, Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>)
```

how can I sort my list by values?

my expected output is something like

```
[the, of, value, v, key, to, given, a, k, map, in, for, this, returns, if, is, super, null, specified, u, function, and, ...]
```

Comment: seems to me they are sorted by value. what output did you expect?

Comment: I can think of a more reproducible example but that output is wrong. it is sorted by keys.

Comment: So you want to sort your map by it's value? Maybe [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values) has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: thanks OH GOD SPIDERS. I do not understand the answer with 986 votes - how would it work in my case?

Comment: It would work in your case the same as it works in any case: You just copy the class and/or method code and use it by passing your Map into it: `Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = MapUtil.sortByValue(counts);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s go through all the issues of your code

1. Name conventions. Method names should start with a lowercase letter.
2. Unnecessary use of `ConcurrentHashMap`. For a purely local use like within you method, an ordinary `HashMap` will do. For parameters, just use the `Map` interface, to allow the caller to use whatever `Map` implementation will fit.
3. Unnecessarily iterating over the `entrySet()`. When you’re only interested in the values, you don’t need to use `entrySet()` and call `getValue()` on every entry; you can iterate over `values()` in the first place. Likewise, you would use `keySet()` when you’re interested in the keys only. Only iterate over `entrySet()` when you need key and value (or want to perform updates).
4. Don’t replace pattern matches by spaces, to split by the spaces afterwards. Specify the (combined) pattern directly to `split`, i.e. `line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\d\\s]+")`.
5. Don’t use `List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value));` unless you specifically need the features of an `ArrayList`. Otherwise, just use `List<String> words = Arrays.asList(value);`
   But when the only thing you’re doing with the list, is `addAll` to another collection, you can use `Collections.addAll(corpus, value);` without the `List` detour.
6. Don’t use `counts.keySet().contains(word)` as you can simply use `counts.containsKey(word)`. But you can simplify the entire

   ```java
   if (counts.containsKey(word)) {
       counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);
   } else {counts.put(word, 1);}
   ```

   to

   ```java
   counts.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
   ```
7. The points above yield

   ```java
   ArrayList<String> corpus = new ArrayList<>();
   for(String line: lemmas.values()) {
       String[] value = line.toLowerCase().trim().split("[\\p{Punct}\\d\\s]+");
       Collections.addAll(corpus, value);
   }
   for (String word : corpus) {
       counts.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
   }
   ```

   But there is no point in performing two loops, the first only to store everything into a potentially large list, to iterate over it a single time. You can perform the second loop’s operation right in the first (resp. only) loop and get rid of the list.

   ```java
   for(String line: lemmas.values()) {
       for(String word: line.toLowerCase().trim().split("[\\p{Punct}\\d\\s]+")) {
           counts.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
       }
   }
   ```
8. You already acknowledged that you can’t sort a map, by copying the map into a list and sorting the list in your first variant. In the second variant, you created a `List<Entry<String, Integer>>` but then, you didn’t use it at all but rather tried to pass the map to `sort`.  (By the way, since Java 8, you can invoke `sort` directly on a `List`, no need to call `Collections.sort`).
   You have to keep copying the map data into a list and sorting the list. For example,

   ```java
   List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());         
   list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
   ```

   Now, you have to decide whether you change the return type to `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` or copy the keys of the sorted entries to a new list.

Taking all points together and staying with the original return type, the fixed code looks like

```java
private static List<String> stopWordsFile(Map<String, String> lemmas) {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    for(String line: lemmas.values()) {
        for(String word: line.toLowerCase().trim().split("[\\p{Punct}\\d\\s]+")) {
            counts.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());         
    list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

    List<String> stopwordslist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: list) stopwordslist.add(e.getKey());

//    System.out.println("List after sorting: " + stopwordslist);
    return stopwordslist;
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much for taking the time to write this  for me!

Comment: the only issue is that I wanted them to be sorted starting with the most frequent words first and get the first 10 or 20 words. list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()) does not work?

Comment: You can replace `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` with `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())`

Comment: yep, that worked!  is there also a way to limit this list to the first 10 words?

Comment: Only after the sorting you know which ten elements are the most frequent. You may extract them like `List<String> topTen = new ArrayList<>(stopwordslist.subList(0, Math.min(10, stopwordslist.size())));`

Comment: There are algorithms for selecting the top *n* elements from a collection without sorting, but they are more complicated and may only pay off when *n* is significantly smaller than the map (you will only know whether they truly pay off after you implemented both alternatives and compared). In fact, the operations used in the answer are so optimized under the hood that they may be faster than a theoretically superior alternative.

Comment: thank you so much! I was experimenting with 10% here, stopwordslist.subList(0, (int) (0.10 * list.size()))

Comment: Keep in mind that a `subList` keeps a reference to the original list, so this might be a case where copying the list into another list like `return new ArrayList<>(stopwordslist.subList(0, …));` is justified, to avoid holding memory occupied longer than necessary.